# sensorLandscape and handling configuration changes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-manifest, android-orientation

I have a game activity which was previously declared as "landscape" in AndroidManifest.xml.

I experimented with using "sensorLandscape" in order to support the reverse landscape mode, and I expected the activity to be recreated each time I rotate it - like the switch from portrait to landscape.

To my surprise, the activity just rotated without recreation (tested on Nexus 4, stock Android ROM).

The question is - can I count on this behavior? Or am I supposed to add code to handle configuration changes just because I support reverse landscape? It looks like I don't need to do anything, but who knows what devices I might encounter... Writing the state saving code might be really time consuming in my project, that's why I'm concerned whether it's even needed.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. Here's what I found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen):

**Note:** When you declare one of the landscape or portrait values, it is considered a hard requirement for the orientation in which the activity runs. **As such, the value you declare enables filtering by services such as Google Play so your application is available only to devices that support the orientation required by your activities.** For example, if you declare either "landscape", "reverseLandscape", or "sensorLandscape", then your application will be available only to devices that support landscape orientation. However, you should also explicitly declare that your application requires either portrait or landscape orientation with the  element. For example, . This is purely a filtering behavior provided by Google Play (and other services that support it) and the platform itself does not control whether your app can be installed when a device supports only certain orientations.

In general - the `sensorLandscape` is not re-creating the `Activity`.

Comment: Regarding the last part - where did you get the information that it's not re-creating the activity? Is there an official documentation for that? I found it to be true on one device, but I don't know if it's a coincidence or a consistent behavior.

Comment: Well, the quotation above is from the official source - the link is there- you can click on the word "here" above.